# Select one column from Type-ORM query - Node

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have a type ORM query that returns five columns. I just want the `company` column returned but I need to select all five columns to generate the correct response.

Is there a way to wrap my query in another select statement or transform the results to just get the `company` column I want?

See my code below:

This is what the query returns currently:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MghEJ.png

I want it to return:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkXJK.png

---

````
  const qb = createQueryBuilder(Entity, 'stats_table');
  qb.select('stats_table.company', 'company');
  qb.addSelect('stats_table.title', 'title');
  qb.addSelect('city_code');
  qb.addSelect('country_code');
  qb.addSelect('SUM(count)', 'sum');

  qb.where('city_code IS NOT NULL OR country_code IS NOT NULL');

  qb.addGroupBy('company');
  qb.addGroupBy('stats_table.title');
  qb.addGroupBy('country_code');
  qb.addGroupBy('city_code');

  qb.addOrderBy('sum', 'DESC');
  qb.addOrderBy('company');
  qb.addOrderBy('title');

  qb.limit(3);

  qb.cache(true);

  return qb.getRawMany();
};```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MghEJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkXJK.png
````

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM didn't meet my criteria, so I'm not experienced with it, but as long as it doesn't cause problems with TypeORM, I see an easy SQL solution and an almost as easy TypeScript solution.

The SQL solution is to simply not select the undesired columns.  SQL will allow you to use fields you did not select in WHERE, GROUP BY, and/or ORDER BY clauses, though obviously you'll need to use 'SUM(count)' instead of 'sum' for the order.  I have encountered some ORMs that are not happy with this though.

The TS solution is to map the return from qb.getRawMany() so that you only have the field you're interested in. Assuming getRawMany() is returning an array of objects, that would look something like this:

getRawMany().map(companyRecord => {return {company: companyRecord.company}});

That may not be exactly correct, I've taken the day off precisely because I'm sick and my brain is fuzzy enough I was making too many stupid mistakes, but the concept should work even if the code itself doesn't.

EDIT:  Also note that map returns a new array, it does not modify the existing array, so you would use this in place of the getRawMany() when assigning, not after the assignment.